# Where to change the value of HZ?

Tags: linux, timer

The value of HZ variable on my current Linux system is 128. I would like to change its value to a higher one, to get a better time resolution. How do I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change linux kernel timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956206/change-linux-kernel-timer)

Answer (score 0):

[Run `make config` or `make xconfig`](http://www.linux.org/threads/the-linux-kernel-configuring-the-kernel-part-1.4274/) and find and set there the value of HZ.